# Sharing classes and methods code among processing scripts

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am writing a set of processing scripts for seismic data acquisition (2D and 3D) planning and geometry processing.   They are very crude scripts (I'm not a developer) that performs the tasks I meant to.   At first they ware developed in the processing environment of QGis 2.x, and I'm porting now to QGis 3.X (working with 3.10 now).

There are a number of functions/classes/methods that are used by some of them.  I would like to be able to put them inside a directory and just import were needed.  Is there any variable in the processing environment pointing to the scripts directory?
e.g.: `~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/.../scripts`

My point is that if I could put those utility code in a directory in the scripts folder, it would be possible to insert that directory in *PYTHONPATH* to have it available during the script run.

Let me know if there is any other approach that can make it possible.  The goal is to have a dynamic way to change it according to the platform or personal configurations.